# How to fix output warning for console window close?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, output

I'm running an `*.exe` file using a batch file and outputting its result in a file. The batch file has the following commands:

```
"..\..\GeneralData\exe\executable.exe" > B:\Simulations\7642\Time_20130101_20130111\output.txt
exit
```

I'm scanning `output.txt` to find when the task was successfully completed. This works well when the application runs with no error because a "Successful finish" string is outputted. The problem is when an error occurs as errors in this application can have multiple codes thus scan for every single option is virtually impossible.

My idea was to output a message when the console window is closed (the exit command executed) and scan the `output.txt` trying to find the "Successful finish" string. If it is not present, it is an error. I was trying to do the following:

```
start /MIN cmd /c "Model.bat || call echo %^errorLevel% > exitcode.txt"
```

But it doesn't output the `exitcode.txt`.
Can someone please give me some clue on how to do this?

Comment: DOS was an operating system in the 80s and 90s. It was used in Windows 9x but not NT systems. We don't refer to the console window or CMD shell as "DOS". The console is a component of Windows that, in recent implementations, consists of the kernel-mode driver condrv.sys and user-mode console host process conhost.exe, which is tightly coupled with the session server csrss.exe. The CMD shell is a Windows application that runs as a console client process that either allocates or inherits a connection to an instance of conhost.exe, unless it's executed as a detached process that has no console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows console errors are usually outputted to STDERR which could be redirected to a file in following manner:

```
executable.exe > output.txt 2> error.txt
```

In case your "executable.exe" provide exitcodes, you could catch it by %errorlevel% value IN THE NEXT LINE of code:

```
executable.exe > output.txt 2> error.txt
if errorlevel 1 process_error.txt_routine
```

Notice that "if errorlevel" clause means, the errorlevel is EQUAL OR HIGHER than given number, so "if errorlevel 0" will be always true.

Comment: You saved my life! Thank you very much!